# Output two numbers (Cops' thread)

Tags: number, cops-and-robbers, busy-beaver

> This is the cops' thread to a [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge.  Click the link to find the [robbers' thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242076/output-two-numbers-robbers-thread).

The challenge here is very simple. Create two programs of the same size, in the same language, which output (using 1 standard output method) two different natural numbers, \$x\$ and \$y\$.  Submit both programs, both numbers and the language used in an answer on this thread.

Robbers will then attempt to find a program in the same language which outputs a number in between \$x\$ and \$y\$, and is the same length as or shorter than your programs.  If they do, they will post it to the [robbers' thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242076/output-two-numbers-robbers-thread), and it is "cracked".

For example If I post:

> ## Haskell, \$9-7 = 2\$, 12 bytes
>
> ```haskell
> main=print 7
> ```
>
> ```haskell
> main=print 9
> ```

Then robbers must find a program that prints `8` in 12 bytes or fewer.

Unlike many challenges in cop's do not need to have an answer in mind when posting.  It is perfectly valid to post an answer which *cannot* be cracked at all.  In fact that is incentivized.  However the scoring means that the better you score the harder it will be to prevent a crack.

### Scoring

Your score will be the difference between \$x\$ and \$y\$.  So in the example answer it was \$2\$.  Higher score is better.  If your answer is cracked it's score is automatically set to 0.

Since there is no hidden information that needs to be revealed, answers will not be marked as safe.  You get your score as soon as you post the answer and it will remain your score until someone cracks it.

Comment: If our language allows us to output an infinite number (R can output ```Inf```, for instance), is a program that outputs this acceptable (for an infinite score if uncracked)?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen No.  `Inf` is not a number as far as this challenge is concerned.

Comment: (And if it were subtraction stops making sense anyway so it's not possible to score)

Comment: Ok.  Related: do answers need to be theoretically correct, or actually runnable on a real implementation of our language?   Example in R: ```2e308``` outputs ```Inf``` (due to overflow of R's numeric type), but in theory it obviously refers to a particular natural number.  Similarly, I suspect that the current Vyxal interpreter will struggle to actually output the intended numbers...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I would argue that `2e308` theoretically refers to `Inf` not an integer.  So it's clear to me that this is a subjective measurement.  Your answer should be correct given enough memory.

Comment: You say "program" in the challenge description - must answers be full programs, or are functions acceptable? Also, must both programs use the same output method, and must robbers' posts also? (I would suggest saying they must)

Comment: @pxeger I would say yes submissions do have to be programs.  Since this is code-golf requiring a full submission just seems like it is more straightforward.  You just tack on whatever boilerplate is required to output if you need to.

Comment: @WheatWizard FYI that invalidates [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242082) already-cracked answer. You also didn't answer my other question about I/O methods, which I think is the more important point

Comment: @pxeger I don't think it's too much of an issue since it's just a boilerplate swap.  `x=>` just had to be replaced with `console.log` or whatever.  Both the underlying problem and the crack are still fine.  I'm not sure how many different IO methods are available to full programs.  They really can only output a string as far as I can tell.  I guess they could have differences in whether they output to STDERR or STDOUT?  If you have an example in mind it would be easier to make a judgement and clarify this precisely.

Comment: @WheatWizard [let us continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133680/room-for-pxeger-and-wheat-wizard)

Comment: Is it required that there be a gap between the two numbers? For example, outputting "1" and "2" would make the job of the robbers impossible.

Comment: @DewiMorgan That's fine but you score very low, so I don't think it's even worth it.

Comment: Does the robber's number need to be natural? For cops it's specified explicitly, but not for robbers.

Comment: If code returns an `OverflowError`, does that invalidate the code, or does it instead mean that a human has to manually calculate what the code returns?

Answer (score 27):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 1 byte, score 124, provably uncrackable

Programs output via exit code.

```
/
```

Outputs 126 ("permission denied"). [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhYL9SE0lAsTBgA)

```
[
```

Outputs 2 ("invalid argument"). [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhYLoyE0lAsTBgA)

Here is a script which tests all 256 possible 1-byte programs, which you can use to verify that this is uncrackable (and unbeatable for 1-byters):

```
{ for c ({0..255}) ( zsh -c ${(#)c} &>/dev/null; echo $? ) } | sort -n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY33aoV0vKLFJIVNKoN9PSMTE1rNRU0FIAqFHSTFVSqNZQ1k2sV1Oz0U1LL9PNKc3KsFVKTM_IVVOwVNBVqFWoUivOLShR08yCmQQ2FGQ4A)

The empty program exits with 0.

Answer (score 13):

## Malbolge, 7 bytes. Score: 3 - 1 = 2. [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242197/61379).

```
D'<;_L"
```

Outputs 3.

```
(&a%M"o
```

Outputs 1.

Comment: That's some Seedprogrammer craziness.

Comment: @null OH! thanks for the hint.

Comment: Lifetime honor: "@null"

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242197/95126).  That was not very easy.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen very cool!

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Wouldn’t this depend on the interpreter? It eventually reaches an invalid instruction after printing 2.

Comment: @user92753 [Languages are defined by their implementations on CGCC](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7833/46076). We don't care whether something depends on the interpreter

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 5 bytes, score: 10^307

```r
1e308
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/3zDV2MDi/38A)

```r
9e307
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/3zLV2MD8/38A)

`2e308` overflows [R](https://www.r-project.org/)'s numeric type, and outputs `Inf`, so I suppose that `1e308` is the highest number that we can output using 5 bytes.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 4 bytes, score: 9 x 10^98, [cracked, almost instantly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242084/95126)

```r
1e99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/3zDV0vL/fwA)

```r
1e98
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/3zDV0uL/fwA)

Note after crack: Well, that was pretty stupid of me.

Comment: Cracked but the question suggests to better make uncrackable solutions

Comment: @i4m2 - Oh, that was stupid of me.

Comment: Note that `3^ceiling(log(9e307,3))` (and variants) are *bigger* than `1e308`, so those are dead ends.

Comment: @Giuseppe - Hm, so I was clearly wrong about 'the highest number that we can output using 5 bytes' then...

Comment: @Giuseppe - (and now I'm quite curious what would be the shortest expression that would output ```1.797693e+308```, assuming that this actually *is* the highest number that can be output in R...)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen It has to be at most 20 bytes, because of `.Machine$double.xmax`

Comment: @Giuseppe: Yes.  Trivially it could be 13 bytes, because of "```1.797693e+308```", but if we disqualify this then "```2^1023*1.9999999``` is only 16...

Answer (score 8):

## C, 24 bytes, score 33482810471

Output format is *decimal*.

```c
main(){printf("%o",~9);}
```

Outputs 37777777766. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0k1X0mnzlLTuvb/fwA)

```c
main(){printf("%u",-1);}
```

Outputs 4294967295. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0m1VElH11DTuvb/fwA)

Uncrackable?

Comment: it's like [here](https://onlinegdb.com/LLMKtjb6c6), often cracked by `main(){printf("%o",.2);}`, but not always.

Answer (score 8):

## Excel, 10 bytes, score <strike>(145!)-(144!)</strike> 0 [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242152/103471)

I'm interested to see how this can be cracked.

```
=FACT(145)
```

Outputs 8.04792605747199E+251 (actually prints every digit when in "Number" format and a very wide column/merged columns, the most I could get it to print before they became ##### or #NUM!

```
=FACT(144)
```

Outputs 5.55029383273931E+249 (again, actually prints every digit [although it does turn most to 0's])

But... if you think it's okay if I can use un-printable numbers (likely not)

## Excel, 10 bytes, score (999999999!)-(999999998!)

```
=FACT(999999999)
```

Output is approximately 1e8448735636

```
=FACT(999999998)
```

Output is approximately (1e8448735636)/999999999

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice answer.

Comment: Thanks! Can I post another answer for another language (C)?

Comment: Sure! Posting multiple answers is fine unless the challenge specifically says not to, even in the same language if they're different enough.

Comment: [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242152/95126)

Comment: (and I assume the dodgy un-printable one is a typo, otherwise surely ```=FACT(100000001)``` is a crack...?)

Comment: Well played @DominicvanEssen! And yes you are correct

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 2 bytes, score: 1000 - 99 = 901

```
Ｉφ
```

Outputs 1000. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEw9DAwEBT0/r///@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code.

```
99
```

Outputs 99. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9/S8v9/AA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal 2.8.1, online edition](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), Score: \$no\$, 102 bytes - [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242091/103772)

Our two programs are:

```
kḭkḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(kḭ(↵
```

which is equivalent to:

```py
stack.append(4294967296)
for i in range(4294967296):
  for j in range(4294967296):
     for l in range(4294967296):
         ...
           stack.append(10 ** stack.pop())
```

and

```
k×k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(k×(↵
```

```py
stack.append(2147483648)
for i in range(2147483648):
  for j in range(2147483648):
     for l in range(2147483648):
         ...
           stack.append(10 ** stack.pop())
```

These both output really big numbers, which I need to calculate. Online edition here means that it should be able to work on the online version of the interpreter if given enough resources and time.

Comment: From the description this seems like it should be really easy to crack.  Simply write a program which loops a set number of times each time applying `↵`. Start at 8 and you should have plenty of room to add 1 at the end.  But I don't know enough about lyxal to make this happen.

Comment: @WheatWizard by the time you've set up the loop, you've already wasted a potential `↵` that could have been used instead

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can set up a loop in fewer than 1000 bytes giving you plenty of time to apply `↵` *way* more than the program which just naively applies `↵` repeatedly.  There is just so much room.

Comment: @WheatWizard "I don't know enough about  *lyxal* to make this happen" lol

Comment: The revised solution still seems vulnerable to the same sort of attack if anyone is enterprising enough to learn Vyxal.

Comment: I doesn't know much about vyxal either bot doesn't something like `eval("kḭ" + "kḭ("*98 + "↵")+1`  is possible with fewer bytes in this language?

Comment: Even if this is easily cracked, another round can always be posted :)

Comment: cracked https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242091/103772

Answer (score 6):

## Jelly, \$1000 - 256 = 744\$, 1 byte

This is provably uncrackable. Our programs are

```
ȷ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///E9v//AQ)

and

```
⁹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R487//wE)

These are the following one byte programs in Jelly that output a number:

```
¤¥¬®µ½×ðȷ !$&*+-.0123456789<=>ACEHLNOPSX^_aceghinoquvw|~°¹²³⁴⁵⁹⁻⁼ẠḄḌẸḤỊṂṆẒȦḂĊḞḢṀṠṪạḅḍịḳḷṇṛ§ẉỵẓȧċḋėġṅȯẇẏ«»‘’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AdoAJf9qZWxsef//VuKCrP///yLCpMKlwqzCrsK1wr3Dl8OwyLcgISQmKistLjAxMjM0NTY3ODk8PT5BQ0VITE5PUFNYXl9hY2VnaGlub3F1dnd8fsKwwrnCsuKBtOKBteKBueKBu@KBvOG6oOG4hOG4jOG6uOG4pOG7iuG5guG5huG6ksim4biCxIrhuJ7huKLhuYDhuaDhuarhuqHhuIXhuI3hu4vhuLPhuLfhuYfhuZvCp@G6ieG7teG6k8inxIvhuIvEl8Sh4bmFyK/huofhuo/Cq8K74oCY4oCZIg)

The two largest outputs are \$1000\$ with `ȷ`, then \$256\$ with `⁹`. Nothing else outputs something in between, and the empty program outputs `0`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 13 bytes, score \$ \approx 10^{(21 \times 10^6)} \$, [cracked by lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/270192)

```sh
tr<=go -c 9 9
```

Outputs 13061918 `9`s. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/pMjGNj1fQTdZwVLB8v9/AA)

```sh
tr<=z3 -c 1 1
```

Outputs 21366224 `1`s. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/pMjGtspYQTdZwVDB8P9/AA)

Exact score:

$$ \frac{10^{21366225} - 1}9 - 10^{13061919} + 1 $$

---

### Explanation

- `<=go`: load the program `go`, as a file
- `tr -c 9 9`: replace all characters except `9`, with `9`s

The other program is similar.

[`z3`](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) and [`go`](https://go.dev) are the largest 2-character programs available on TIO, at about 22MB and 14MB respectively. We can use them as an easy source of very long "strings", and by converting all the bytes to digits, very large numbers.

I used TIO instead of ATO because it has much bigger binaries available, and also because ATO is too frequently updated, changing the binaries, so the score would change over time.

I'm not intending for this to be cracked, but I haven't tried very hard to ensure there aren't any cracks.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/270192/3852)

Answer (score 4):

### Seed 4791 bytes, 9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9 - 9^999

9^999:

```
36                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         94981479280208146944953816764699944095961978453221682715159791056688140996853888504437229889191975183564015323273899198344481103250895668467924054339223701930305051118652741561583994582158440585564368286547479926974178096702473601294217332487135194413906552257837173590043556058790275467394479137424662603752651645938216669070115921033298764330851330467996807939281657656425699237251690473743679487474871854542411596819130830481224340562767172942708101325192086341055751991333028615416686839981817142945819118242545846019740984523396598771709676467792891959285529685021033906795910583508008242630927336057598688291102981549916746769870319488733952651891371543582899041173842586806720961829689851873808965388202504531747804845840143327859796447099370149069303515672221742322125494895020945918848068614407697751238250677431155329740069260038983064746127731524766636439066019193467422893766041808161143968190057861269526918372578995949004970306694838999565427329694454909226376047136625534400886807619996259128667499478409012349612038652572951348047086088817551011308002652053644287503036935028935844715426527836055671911027719964392826069078969082698559771882396772799751373195780148811909716528980696256380945795001274573193459618177342958415946401666965464920052072906030975414694315792619540688825293711591412127002343225335880571865520167604325308977304908296745198902342257861540933487039862994356564924690417285711172056255742252487361407255067571158083586073346420212617420441279183030666063290178409730490381049078147916881460523911120507498436875929418470544681759185903900133455626013012351989728905311148323498044351461599265083429729804099930581137436822766380518345367947616841345549577232164529955502684122270790499052240935152809235771171370434070236688989688479953925955276348719434668321141480227864703028324596206817015011573827251621510788266231733052888294086085254666969188534237535939663347385652634046245668458458194635071661213214973469115822380087405654270393830651870914063112038485264582625501640551679797243637993058707669484199371425261416836151503596151478053438581656553121438841132537636618059562148278640553730409617733965555456279846109188629372980642417837804453861796471345795684171211276475918979481722058104857844758843603165344900677433585454487342231624372104550191735735796454388857238022368193594741972999621272782164771208619698294562775042889372442244124800173695001811951104483064798795939319310120564380578007164764614616015236574253569882284714066981102630472310220979239145467130016229967089894017391315803929147667149546926923076190028432304251122963960242247834461462078725734648747107996037476017483441942628448413731020112504750795380529669192191584807395775799602140589910229189049503739591898879818034929487479963008540786045617483659914745637538236332799035903698998398005069763801222822678189343269224348393728495631906613048781189537304930344768279627715649280517720235827779507044205103495831324708746293837927334289124220386247007983741488271118125085904363197981352562772119852399632426650691964453022658894369910133959424146640109164371294689079802777902307296880648093189854866622499839863241317182736088299334215289137396403643588453171937501380801955934324623689028726948232299713278675563351730787914169555473591390989160245212337001718142110638979369841824007070047204941161283902352728852331043554053279968108315668988738506810443190205259224591564532510273789237748335782790807545071073495745130501275790665780813262239133252704358246589268608658852890888957950256512957031746836236764704856568474359369600518287601870385217873471559723711460790851490641852774919778389159824024349093647531524452566965015853360104186115940302479291089022327363165427092882556283691659718308627299377279772911302647604701234001616842762253575818861145567617316017544857744939000573784180397907315361706557618352235994622697878150716754864959319585660748889125094235883962411794008488384621978956654775262754623280713877112553348864910614097062301093879722439179562871939066598227413212667524976059454125001698534620701802564422768614905506319489756942407153064671390062115508534001167416000467035978170537796335329422124742348973353594178675864912238921028339003101191208960656005489477745423235808264714405884454620918978113027106595440238470298437388674769792190539877475662105937286759309442118449241650440411271188409657695505912558859008915175033843314270463991607598704331221534023888995395090620691204768
```

This generates the following befunge programs:

```
 "cb 0=HTGNEL_ENIL_CB|'999^9' ohce"=@
```

Thanks to [@null](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87986/null) for reminding me I know how to program Seed.

The second program becomes:

```
53 309587622060800553797768779768494911841628261184767731489332912878541825672886566188681588715091427880831872903145865614752063676670384244697938284581157766493625127486069966517483807267622940281840537784840565165614923074081025668091978619573378790644656852906050466371773524417205893183522285682501264293869247195711547240624794051171506566110127196684091043263704047601080904572252690239932534180485242573593166277713560062201443018547580753558753076249237708886730792578837512812594738578149293808173180907025198002544953022811343070481719591552371661589667292782400655709462087966594005437890287977681252692413309430402819975448488893242566687723971049600796250960915479240241523929324115544908597729425622791811471173026530746268048270787941195246863033941763322474063945991208609412842541131320624405655371178829432647519162966803019160693234110850310536828203057708491223327429158504206916042083919635627816797751112595799425150793221319690691484648035817244488524453691950153293122568235889159354407000681042368350613187209832365401659548342971503410960096851577419002008732886164772578445903853439006453593714967313295474365940623318333595448104799161502690614815839414921869269173019141656145770493252423864457874164529445010976172453560422794168628767033007798464857807868972770119452458362389906963282436285266581231736927418149622919396524509045600877152139736196549699718010709692427212834211798096407951361607408561365539352799316609116886495092220026475056054004109655559238156190632938794875725763241934373532462961173950124119350519950416535961630182879968505149425984423718446515752555953370146281257558975704887791656829772389610358616172108023688683194195646087461491617635517077426354405251289450350884001525808934031920441467238068082960111819700136750591936811451950869796830795917902563838207457238199783664676631034747422610392737824936385217739329722785171995265543924626358418544733893242621181268907981435590946535967453087735571432009511302485790035630081692234070829135516653019636470143030262426164209059107313322273527988454852167740639604116654661106183147469766915633812512660623654733210776980513357988371975078629660700128024350111565369418799322994425194707442766131638194451296869655903560930552909726193906116203105280133098173487874636694252312563326834465786203019871459621428412218125660006856353034700431931551987177749720765277804188429325209144778878250052168648774014287051224303669581052487796035601212899803091980714662821531796312403019296375399485542097354585848372838776512451340890861805997089465652085241774190551963641174852103085029950949878525880282522636862689978529309241328139079974474498840789713396190657697469158669210302848644464901861283874879947038142675120700972350655160123482902871840054575564022314230414143498863246180321421107093159843511652846289238887904021891711361912352395752690348787554827002831376719081050720410310253594459120692911078678989959842508193061754966247315287630553272097166145570047781427011192833631466194493500860462029105164607250519256275264184570393514673731241768380866974597977047998254748735616785609554132052392767706860844358763762550597658505611387104158401413665230304581335849536972107107380977005367190725149287488469722296267278310609063864272116083546208401737358229303260037829564529791746229429584305623876048177048606434240808955564817647762135226292996457376569825840317487337230342808888439404782377044367241171285682843079144996791352785027653912966489528982369346460394462814510925432325649339476445012957862795528485420766725202232921562144249478994398630291247115812027459339439917745701011664764129641934911394405527525162982448137755434800132266423495736646406665020110921399145992639873000772187319349501446035997970338236156282496731462537470287250998341901639931110985832053143995593295587994998629729807528492791923904555457866017778430904246471024077597359827409642434169201834219584106992783524218181235229797375275600542981388826320938305229269139948945723602080721878638825973118853705899013952011812734028557886010265443351247058659869796789367980202658727913440606028570394873456111539589719778807886159735916680268655045949064003143304502567591948483646514438384066523522818325855415617165015245093826574834982063177898711249371505888565014662311628585433493237461213627490980308832056414074306954654643982609793175536357731519819711214704220198179035754939835716988611721494310455897591499137450735143359976295914194929864424760941191508944873123510109598842071064171881097121958831073339652141908077795821260390971306588642697066016462777462135092080108211612548519054989094919411477432604519350786361891036501628076178403464320215611778222267688190891672404404679274514697484921192422288645990934995323948756777118204678605373179302677235930726235223857
```

The first one can be padded with spaces to it's length. It expands to the following:

```
"cb 0=HTGNEL_ENIL_CB|'9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9' ohce"=@
```

The score:

\$10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{8.567841344463465}}}}}}}}}\$

Comment: If you can pad a seed program with spaces doesn't the first one crack the second one?

Comment: oh oops... you've seen nothing.

Comment: Do you have an interpreter that actually works?  My seed interpreter has limits on how large an exponent can be.

Comment: `36` (15 chars)

Comment: @WheatWizard it's a mildly theoretical submission. It's just `bc` doing all the computations behind the hood, judging by the Befunge code it generates. You probably don't have enough memory to generate the bigger number.

Comment: Since the answer is available from the edit history [it was only a matter of time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242087/56656).  Sorry.

Comment: @WheatWizard you didn't crack my answer, I wrote this code. I don't think it's fair to claim it under your name.
If anything, I cracked my solution myself. (accidentally)

Comment: Well it is cracked. You are free to dislike it, or to write a new answer.

Comment: You didn't crack it :). And I refuse to acknowledge the crack.

Comment: Sure, you cracked it for me.  It is cracked.

Comment: I agree with Wheat Wizard here that this answer is cracked since there is a program that fulfills the requirements of cracking it. It acknowledges Kamila as the cracker, which is fine.

Answer (score 4):

## Brainf*ck, 25 bytes. Score = 7 - 4 = 3, [cracked by Fmbalbuena](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242093/96037)

```
>>+++++[<+++++++++++>-]<.
```

[^ Outputs 7](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fzk4bBKJttBHATjfWRu//fwA)

```
>++++[<+++++++++++++>-]<.
```

[^ Outputs 4](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fThsIom20kYGdbqyN3v//AA)

I just learned Brainf***, I think it's going to be an easy crack.

Comment: [For future reference :)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants)

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242093/106959)

Comment: @DomHastings Oh, thanks.

Comment: I hope you took that the way it was intended! It was truly about sharing knowledge, it's not something I'd seen until I'd played with BF a lot so thought it might be useful to you!

Comment: @DomHastings Nice, searched for a bit on google if there are any shorter approaches, but didn't find anything, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes, score = 61803398875 - 14159265359 = 47644133516

```
φṫb₂ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//3zbw52rkx41NT3c3f3///8oAA)

```
πṫb₂ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//3zDw52rkx41NT3c3f3///8oAA)

#### Explanation

Not sure this is crackable:

```
φ        Take Phi = 1.61803398875
π        Or Pi = 3.14159265359
 ṫ       Convert to string
  b₂     Remove the first digit and the decimal separator
    ị    Convert back to integer
```

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242102/52210)

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 1 [byte](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py), score 100000000-10000000=90000000

100,000,000: `↕`
10,000,000: `◄`

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9R21SFR9Nb/v8HAA)

I would be surprised if this is crackable..

Comment: I read the source and saw `random.seed(1)` and hoped, but [`v` + `--unittest` couldn't save me...](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7/s//9/@QUlmfl5xf91dUvzMktKUotLAA "MathGolf – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 63 bytes, score \$2\rightarrow12\rightarrow(9^{99}-1)-2\rightarrow11\rightarrow(9^{99}-1)\$

Program 1:

```python
A=lambda m,n:m and A(m-1,n<1or A(m,n-1))or-~n
print(A(9**99,8))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39E2JzE3KSVRIVcnzypXITEvRcFRI1fXUCfPxjC/CMTWydM11NTML9Kty@MqKMrMK9Fw1LDU0rK01LHQ1Pz/HwA)

Program 2:

```python
A=lambda m,n:m and A(m-1,n<1or A(m,n-1))or-~n
print(A(9**99,9))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39E2JzE3KSVRIVcnzypXITEvRcFRI1fXUCfPxjC/CMTWydM11NTML9Kty@MqKMrMK9Fw1LDU0rK01LHU1Pz/HwA)

This just calculates the difference between two nearby invocations of the Ackermann function.

Comment: I'm getting a recursion error? infinite recursion for both...

Comment: @12944qwerty They give a recursion error because Python (nor any language on any computer) cannot actually practically compute `A(9*99,8)`; it's too large a number

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 22 bytes, Score=\$\frac 19\times 10^{10000000}-\frac 19\$, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242097/)

```javascript
x=>'8'.repeat(9999999)

x=>'9'.repeat(9999999)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f@/wtZO3UJdryi1IDWxRMMSAjT///@vW5YDAA)

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 19 bytes, Score=\$3\times 10^{254}\$, unlikely crackable

```javascript
+[+++++>+<]+[>.<+]

+[+++++>+<]++[>.<+]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO1obBOy0bWK1o@30bLRj////r1uWAwA)

Comment: p.s. I have no solution for this

Comment: Both programs must be the same size. The first one is only 18 bytes?

Comment: @Dingus Add space if you like

Comment: Yeah just realised any no-op would do.

Comment: What's the second JavaScript program?

Comment: @ThisFieldIsRequired Added

Comment: Cracked: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242097/106710

Answer (score 2):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), score \$11111111111111111\$, 121 bytes

Both programs use the following method:

1. Output a string of 26 digits
2. Make 16 copies of those digits and append them to the end.

#### Program 1:

Outputs `9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999988888888888888888` (425 `9`s then 17 `8`s).

```bash
a:
*=>\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\8
b:
[]$1=>$1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1
```

#### Program 2:

Outputs
`9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999` (442 `9`s).

```bash
a:
*=>\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9
b:
[]$1=>$1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1 $1
```

### Minimal answer: score \$9-8=1\$, 8 bytes

```bash
# program 1
a:
*=>\8
# program 2
a:
*=>\9
```

Answer (score 1):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), 6 bytes, score: 1001001, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242232/106959) by emanresu

```
(#)
```

The first three bytes are char code 127.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P@/vr5eQ1nz/38A)

```
~~~(#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P@/rq5OQ1nz/38A)

> You can't see the solution, But this is easy

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242076/output-two-numbers-robbers-thread/242232#242232

Comment: @emanresuA Good crack

Answer (score 1):

## [MATLAB](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 1.797693e+308 - 1.797047e+308 = 6.463132e+304, 7 bytes

```
realmax
```

outputs 1.797693e308

```
5175^83
```

outputs 1.797047e+308

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/KDUxJzexgovL1NDcNM7C@P9/AA)

Comment: I think this is easily cracked by `1e10` -- also you can use [Octave](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/KDUxJzexgks3M68kNzOPyzDV0OD/fwA) for a close approximation to MATLAB. MATL is based on MATLAB but is a very different language!

Comment: Updated to fix that, and hopefully made it harder to crack

Comment: [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242295/67312)

Comment: Try again! good luck

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 41 bytes, score=\$2.82×10^{456573}-2.82×10^{446573}\$, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242076/output-two-numbers-robbers-thread/242222#242222)

```
import math
print(math.factorial(100000))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCE3sSSDq6AoM69EA8TUS0tMLskvykzM0TA0AAFNzf//AQ)

```
import math
print(math.factorial(99999))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCE3sSSDq6AoM69EA8TUS0tMLskvykzM0bAEAU3N//8B)

This is embarrassing i forgot that you can just do 3*10**456573

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242076/output-two-numbers-robbers-thread/242222#242222)

Comment: By the way, the lengths of the programs are different from each other. They should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP4, score ≈ 0.011 × 10^1000

**Program 1** (23 chars) output `999` times `9` :

```php
echo str_repeat(9,999);
```

**Program 2** (23 chars) output `999` times `8` :

```php
echo str_repeat(8,999);
```

Output of both PHP4 scripts is a 999 digits integer in decimal form.

```php
var_dump(chop($out_1, '0..9') === ''); // bool(true)
var_dump(chop($out_2, '0..9') === ''); // bool(true)
```

*[BC Math](https://www.php.net/manual/en/bc.installation.php) is only available if PHP was configured with `--enable-bcmath`, by default there is not.*