# Output two numbers (Robbers' thread)

Tags: number, cops-and-robbers, busy-beaver

> This is the robbers' thread to a [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge.  Click the link to find the [cops' thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242075/output-two-numbers-cops-thread).

In the [cops' thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242075/output-two-numbers-cops-thread) of this challenge, answerers will be writing programs which output two numbers, \$x\$ and \$y\$.  As robbers, your goal will be to crack their submissions.  To do this, you find a program in the same language as a cop's program which outputs a number in between \$x\$ and \$y\$, and is the same length as or shorter than the cop's program.  Your program must use the same output method as the cop's submission.

You submit that program here and notify the cop in a comment on their answer.

For every answer you crack here you get 5 points.  As an extra incentive you will gain an additional point for every byte shorter your program is than the cop's.  If your program is the same length, that is fine; you still get 5 points.

The winner is the person with the highest total score across all answers.

Answer (score 15):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), 6 bytes, cracks [Kamila Szewczyk's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242077/95126)

```
(&<`q#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/19DzSahUPn/fwA) (or try it [here](https://malbolge.doleczek.pl/#) to avoid timing-out)

Outputs 2.

**Explanation**.
The goal is to output the ASCII character "`2`" in a 7-byte or less program.

Malbolge code & data occupies the same memory space.  When a Malbolge program is loaded, the last two single-byte instructions act as 'seeds' that determine how the remaining memory is initialized (in a deterministic but rather uncontrollable fashion).  So if we try to construct 5 command/byte programs that use the contents of the memory to generate the ASCII encoding for "`2`", we can try different combinations of the remaining 2 commands/bytes to try to find one that gives the correctly-initialized memory to achieve this.  There are 8 valid Malbolge commands (and any other byte in the program will generate an error upon loading), so this gives us 8x8 combinations to try per 5 byte program.  This is obviously less than the 1/256 chance of 'hitting' the ASCII character "`2`" in any particular byte, so we'll probably have to try more than one program.

Each Malbolge command self-modifies immediately after execution, making re-use rather difficult.  So here we try only single-pass programs, without any attempt to loop.  We will need to use the commands `j` (set the data pointer), `<` (write an ASCII value to the output), and (probably) `v` (end the program).  This gives us room for 2 more data-altering commands in within the 5-byte limit, so we can try combinations of `*` (rotate) and `p` (tritwise OP operation), as well `o` (no operation; but in Malbolge this changes the data pointer as a side effect so it can also affect the output).

Unfortunately, after trying all 64 combinations of the final two bytes across the Malbolge programs `jpo<v..`, `jop<v..`, `ojp<v..`, `jpp<v..`, `jppp<v.`, `jpppp<v`, `j*o<v..`, `j*p<v..`, `j*pp<v.` and `j*ppp<v` (where `.` represents any of the 8 Malbolge commands), we can only generate the output numbers 0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.  At this point it seems likely that [Kamila Szewczyk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61379/kamila-szewczyk) may have used a similar approach, and therefore hoped that generating the character "`2`" in 7 bytes or less is impossible...

But: what about shorter programs that omit the `v` (end the program) command?  These allow the memory to be initialized differently, and so we can maybe find a combination that enables output of "`2`"... but the Malbolge interpreter will now continue reading bytes from the rest of the initialized memory and executing them as commands, with rather uncontrollable consequences!  Still, if it hits a `v` (end of program) before it hits a `<` (write output), that could be Ok: so let's try it!

After some searching, we find that `j*p<..` is indeed able to initialize the memory to output "`2`", using two different suffix combinations: when test-run, `<j` unfortunately keeps running and outputs an additional "`2L`" before stopping, but `/j` stops after the "`2`".  It's a crack!

To load into Malbolge, the final program - `j*p</j` - must finally be encoded using a series of operations (see the [spec](https://web.archive.org/web/20190417235149/http://www.lscheffer.com/malbolge_spec.html)) to yield the final loadable code of `` (&<`q# ``.

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242083/), 4 bytes

```r
2e98
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/3yjV0uL/fwA)

Not much fun but the range makes it cracked

Answer (score 9):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>26 18</s> 14 bytes (88 bytes saved)

Crack of [@lyxal's vyxal cop program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242085/103772)

```
k×:\(+33*\↵+Ė›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJrw5c6XFwoKzMzKlxc4oa1K8SW4oC6IiwiIiwiIl0=)

output lowest bound +1

(first time doing vyxal, tell me if I did something incorrectly)

### Explanation

```
k×         Push 2147483648 onto the stack
           => [2147483648]
:          Duplicate the stack
             => [2147483648, 2147483648]
\(+        Concatenate the last element of the stack with `(`
             => [2147483648, '2147483648(']
33*        Multiply by 33 the string on top of the stack
             => [2147483648, '2147483648(21 ... 8(2147483648(']
\↵+        Add `↵` to the string on top of the stack
             => [2147483648, '2147483648(21 ... 8(2147483648(↵']
Ė          Evaluate as vyxal code the last element of the stack (see the cop thread)
             => [ <lowest bound> ]
›          Add 1 to the result
             => [ <lowest bound +1> ]
           implicit output
```

Comment: :`( are you sad?

Comment: C+: no I'm happy

Comment: rip the old version of the code where these ^ jokes ^ made sense T_T

Answer (score 8):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/wiki/Code-page) (0 bytes saved), 20922789888

```
16ḟ↔↔
```

Outputs \$20\text{,}922\text{,}789\text{,}888\$.

Cracks [@Fatalize's Brachylog Cop answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242089/52210), which is also 5 bytes and the range \$14\text{,}159\text{,}265\text{,}359\$ to \$61\text{,}803\text{,}398\text{,}875\$.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/39Ds4Y75j9qmANH///@jAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
16ḟ    # Push the factorial of 16: 20922789888000
   ↔   # Reverse (but remain an integer): 88898722902
    ↔  # Reverse back: 20922789888
```

Comment: Clever use of reverse on integers!

Answer (score 6):

## Excel, 6 bytes, cracks [Luke Dunn's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242132/95126)

```
=1E250
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/39bQ1cjU4P9/AA)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 22 bytes

```javascript
x=>'9'.repeat(1e7-1)-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1k7dUl2vKLUgNbFEwzDVXNdQU9fwf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGpub//7plOQA)

This cracks [l4m2's cop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242082/106710).

Works only in theory. The string in the answer, with `9999999` golfed to `1e7-1`, minus 1, which coerces it to a number.

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 22 bytes

```javascript
x=>'909'.repeat(1e7/3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1k7d0sBSXa8otSA1sUTDMNVc31jzf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGpub//7plOQA)

Works in reality.

This one exploits the fact that the repetition count is rounded down.

Comment: Intended solution `x=>'9'.repeat(1e7-2)+1`

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 15 bytes (10 bytes saved), cracks [mathcat's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242092)

```
-[>+<-----]>++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pO20YXBGLttLX1/v8HAA)

Answer (score 3):

## pxeger's zsh, 13 bytes

```sh
tr<=z3 -c 0 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/pMjGtspYQTdZwUDB8P9/AA)

Cracks https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242150/3852

Comment: It's suddenly so obvious!

Comment: Nice! I feel stupid now...

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 6 bytes, cracks [robbie crockett's first answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/242293/2)

```matlab
28^213
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/V@UmpiTm1jx38gizsjQ@H9OfrqGoZ55qrGBhaY@iGNkofkfAA)

Found by a brute force search of `n` where `log(1.7e308,n)` is very close but less than an integer so that `n^ceiling(log(1.7e308,n))` is not too large.

Comment: I updated it. Good luck with the new one

Answer (score 1):

## [Seed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242086/56656), 4695 bytes (96 byte save), \$9^{999999999999999}\$

```
48 136118222288577729572552152791709368605773628347021471008690822115373392141244799774415998107055377981742447271161172093778621602759645881735548840779482802560209189517746243033627985739511100518293138471484155429274889918272710559291982273929396912514475806069037521031407489333870378703173662910402083164029699758795021006600087782123480276870349030965867563726975877728510764214971834340717031826050329624446895168002822671009104546726772407954859794475567312583905626817398451742396403319735329821368897163429801670218889821848435198982270769585133239840182076928600225425386926305906233725574337009104530356853863448383654832344408718772724757372631143287400290703116853900133240035664821661976772888810467002790969870927064001031662898740474966711631710727286951427698675681491111582579107155062882709864229052873760966169264245600186093538370974908907020474070930611562816292100183878427364763405389786799631792649382212389347264227332059441821014321577413408905755610100524739302573178913805937883513832378054230283344383753275902621779919104894612137194747465109053363132937703205299899090062685892622098070989799300096851455096301228710972701865038051936551041342440525433281771038877777161882636844059426594521805350407152290165733138028576146967247522643744694141195004623423857857693427850032738203686267421228588828435013088446245077772203162760491431357812801871298876631302950079959010177847566668826266369346040779302669462790393198104623019338124802383380441313038602352462845958086644089497490467594136351122837597449672487010313897868432189301305885675861325709179122431375903938149903427353406026693988298068066087414204535567217531278847246663063521026232422013930241593518848232749733716027932971967899916260405600669083231342566885341691912368360136490149146410247155251733391927312938665018633466748949229241307444214633067906713336048685943513134140263372359696945716406670478168007378272916725550905826132341140883161990841937113616809856754859509173906225877693272986499970529936397933788880924831441272134709649991804869975215537765013304261103280798035738449283801074367455416975896866833656686794976325679828000354046625307811860168996790355272279436375392093313679100121487235860221918848736347751782535229777178218227648706506003129525970134666691479694925217524902959803338422438060038658440582225592904612537669959087757488373578611752282868269275950214371229748731729215641332246654869362216109284862185496124584262579953474203167872603070470067950478753207808608248943878860011908115468802190546000519840247324568161439611525769820989196058123147718137077000120913662868599382356603269721601449988482683980532792892177658333875496383645485133701798213530386049902190319666619680418627484562095523349838908554879800729189834397636333150687591784783593636695475815080002634570530677847790228554244311329470586241698758265462755938042304017099033993858637076639260904636077951244351657896256391998258900387543477862789459882688297086948688007197707992577339183010173354065933555655553421866069534486864447491231024219783356908661520568506172333653043056654975852125377780460189002009695349728259441892176823884813139372756407875800289098734167129099381792737264454097003678873187452677901588877289663613161551851497712147029113595405001612731177702538079055158748598170770058186080901509151495332123511968083584199679029073876741472874261160159173180904406481520378171876773781817052362670957754076341052151226864982044423001068087857032658832611786035188675526138932008287577260700322890640413383485742814765880396419208969263227721270455088178847430617675460588467868983618120954389404362140231158416321704501412371098629111850576048849097883084678663620297477847964712187292115607313892012356396662805274189107494467684644891521782414262128173708455480707454354968100553678330533006106890027275388315886464487511584246560889155661821779830187538375406868333151665726444207031130208083500148213129337075506341798868095841311106337887887291979827246042278337117981115263174824668396544795084846659779500193321324649508077325582071348037416574693493790019348532848623137704882189995492207319495341511822520469501170794388924439459462165936478786200751196030621197856797511117488998623310034898658778486649937046992404397946797175451641601275425983240032855623615931663152448038884938302103599522781131691794955910668601656339114328483085213740867710698818388423094906297631419655436847220572682142406966844544894284269328182913703189411753835932978396033829515305455631318696053728968876051410783596705077112312728424202529475578776676152981258884551184505959739004252170359641105692336889964755135425463797747654176970663980003607348930037794652574271713970
```

Nothing clever on my part I stole this from the answer's edit history.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://python.org), <strike>19</strike> 16 bytes (saves <strike>22</strike> 25 bytes)

```py
print(3*10**456570)
```

Cracks [DialFrost's cop answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242221/97819)... I just did a bunch of trial and error to get this lol.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew1JLy8TcwsTMSPP/fwA).
[Verify it's between the two numbers](https://tio.run/##ZY29DoMwDIR3P4XFRBiq/qC2VJR3cSsokRISJV54@tQh6lBxk3Xfnc@vPLvlkpK23gVGSzzDS3/wuZ2Hid7sgiZTn45ZCqIlY/a4y1JASxTWNU17u7fXM4CesDQGFPYAFPmgF64rdq6wSsFoJJjLA8r6LibeForjH6JV3HLnbp9zP6Os9vmpSukL)

Comment: `9**478462` saves 3 more bytes. (It should be a way to do `x**x**x` to save even more bytes but I don't have the patience to find it

Answer (score 1):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), 6 bytes, cracks [Fmbalbuena's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242231/100664)

```
~(#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P@/rr5eQ1nz/38A)